xanmod and virtualbox problem
$ wget -qO - https://dl.xanmod.org/archive.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -vo /usr/share/keyrings/xanmod-archive-keyring.gpg
[sudo] password for mtl: 
gpg: writing to '/usr/share/keyrings/xanmod-archive-keyring.gpg'
gpg: armor header: Version: GnuPG v2

$ echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/xanmod-archive-keyring.gpg] http://deb.xanmod.org releases main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xanmod-release.list
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/xanmod-archive-keyring.gpg] http://deb.xanmod.org releases main

$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-xanmod-x64v3
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]         
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.xanmod.org releases InRelease [2,091 B]                        
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports InRelease [59.0 kB]       
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3,590 B]      
Get:7 http://deb.xanmod.org releases/main amd64 Packages [44.7 kB]              
Get:8 http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-fasttrack InRelease [12.9 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main Sources.diff/Index [63.3 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [63.3 kB]
Get:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [19.1 kB]
Get:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages [18.8 kB]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main Sources T-2024-10-17-0206.14-F-2024-10-16-0806.33.pdiff [1,872 B]
Get:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [18.9 kB]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main Sources T-2024-10-17-0206.14-F-2024-10-16-0806.33.pdiff [1,872 B]
Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2024-10-16-2005.16-F-2024-10-16-1406.32.pdiff [1,276 B]
Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2024-10-16-2005.16-F-2024-10-16-1406.32.pdiff [1,276 B]
Hit:16 https://repo.waydro.id bookworm InRelease                                
Get:17 https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-backports-staging InRelease [12.9 kB]
Fetched 425 kB in 2s (228 kB/s)       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbus-glib-1-2 linux-headers-6.1.0-22-amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-22-common linux-headers-6.1.0-23-amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-23-common linux-image-6.1.0-22-amd64
  linux-image-6.1.0-23-amd64
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libelf-dev linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libelf-dev linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 linux-xanmod-x64v3
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 107 MB of archives.
After this operation, 627 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 libelf-dev amd64 0.188-2.1 [72.9 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.xanmod.org releases/main amd64 linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 amd64 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005 [9,695 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.xanmod.org releases/main amd64 linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 amd64 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005 [97.4 MB]
Get:4 http://deb.xanmod.org releases/main amd64 linux-xanmod-x64v3 amd64 6.11.3-xanmod2-0 [912 B]                                                                              
Fetched 107 MB in 20s (5,356 kB/s)                                                                                                                                             
Selecting previously unselected package libelf-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 369330 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libelf-dev_0.188-2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libelf-dev:amd64 (0.188-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2_6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2_6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-xanmod-x64v3.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-xanmod-x64v3_6.11.3-xanmod2-0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-xanmod-x64v3 (6.11.3-xanmod2-0) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005) ...
Setting up libelf-dev:amd64 (0.188-2.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005) ...
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 KVER=6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2.....
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/wl.ko
Cleaning build area...

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2/updates/dkms/
depmod....
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 -C /lib/modules/6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.12/build......(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.12/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_gsc_1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bmg_dmc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/xe2lpd_dmc.bin for module i915
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/luks-77c6d073-978b-47c4-a0fa-a3cea61b9c08)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-26-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-26-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-25-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
done
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-xanmod-x64v3:
 linux-xanmod-x64v3 depends on linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2; however:
  Package linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-xanmod-x64v3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
 linux-xanmod-x64v3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried to remove VirtualBox but I ran into the following error:
mtl@macbookair:~$ sudo apt remove virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbus-glib-1-2 libgsoap-2.8.124 liblzf1 libtpms0 libvncserver1 linux-headers-6.1.0-22-amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-22-common linux-headers-6.1.0-23-amd64
  linux-headers-6.1.0-23-common linux-headers-6.1.0-25-amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-25-common linux-image-6.1.0-22-amd64 linux-image-6.1.0-23-amd64 linux-image-6.1.0-25-amd64
  virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 187 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 394590 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-ext-pack (7.0.12-2~fto12+1) ...
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Successfully uninstalled "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
Successfully performed extension pack cleanup
Removing virtualbox-qt (7.0.12-dfsg-1~fto12+1) ...
Removing virtualbox (7.0.12-dfsg-1~fto12+1) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2-0~20241012.g9751005) ...
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 -C /lib/modules/6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.12/build......(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.12/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_gsc_1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bmg_dmc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/xe2lpd_dmc.bin for module i915
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/luks-77c6d073-978b-47c4-a0fa-a3cea61b9c08)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-26-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-26-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-25-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
done
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-xanmod-x64v3:
 linux-xanmod-x64v3 depends on linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2; however:
  Package linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-xanmod-x64v3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.11.3-x64v3-xanmod2
 linux-xanmod-x64v3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What did I miss?
